# Set chart theme via controller extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, colors, charts

I'm trying to set a custom theme to a chart view like this :

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.backlogTheme', {
extend: 'Ext.chart.theme.Base', 
constructor: function(config) {
    this.callParent([Ext.apply({           
        colors: ['#000000', 
                         '#000F05', 
                         '#001F0A', 
                         '#002E0F', 
                         '#003D14'
                ],
    }, config)]);
}
});
Ext.define('Proj.controller.ChartRender', {
   extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
   ...//Controller config
chartRender: function () {
    var chart = this.getChart(); //my Chart view
    chart.theme = 'backlogTheme';
}
})
```

But it won't work unless I do it directly on the Chart view, but the problem is that I want to set the theme dynamically.

How can I do it please?